# I want to start a new project but I am not sure how to approach this: i want to make a client like app for the user and a cloud backend

Tags: python, cloud, chatbot, software-design

I want to try and make a really advance Virtual Assistant and I want it to work somehow like google assistant by connecting to an account. Also I don't feel like its a good idea to give the user all the code (compiled into exe or whatever) so I want to make a client app for the user (something like the game League of Legends has)

Do you have any ideas on how I can make this? I have medium knowledge of programming so I am not familiar with this type of coding.

Comment: first learn basis. next try to do so complex task. First you have to learn to create web page with API - ie. using `FastAPI` or `Flask`, `Django`, etc. And later you can try to create client application which will use this API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cant comment yet, so I have to write it here. It depends on whether you want to use a UDP server or a TCP server to work between your client and database/cloud. The main difference is that a UDP server works by packaging up the data that needs to be sent through (done by either the backend or the client), sent through the server, and the reciever (also either a client or backend) will unpackage the data, and do what it what it will.
I am not super familiar with TCP servers, but I know Python is built with the ability to work with both without having to install an extra package. I added a link to give you a better understanding of both:

https://dev.to/black_strok3/difference-between-udp-and-tcp-example-code-1pg1

HTTP servers are also an option, if you were wanting to have the client work as a web-based app, but if you were wanting to have Python as your backend, I think having a python-based client and backend would be better (since you tagged Python in this post).